# Can I set texture filtering for uploaded texture?

Tags: javascript, html, model-viewer

### The Challenge

The goal is to display the uploaded image pixelated, with `NEAREST` texture filtering.

### What I tried so far

1. Using CSS' `image-rendering` property.
2. Setting the .glb model filters to `NEAREST`.

### What I think the problem is

I think the issue is that the images that come with the model are properly filtered, but the new uploaded one isn't.

### Interesting Links I've Found

[Model Viewer Materials API](https://modelviewer.dev/examples/scenegraph/#pickMaterialExample)

### Example

```js
document.getElementById("urlA").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const file = this.files[0];
  const viewer = document.getElementById("modelA");

  if (!file) return;

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', async function() {
    const texture = await viewer.createTexture(reader.result);
    viewer.model.materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness.baseColorTexture.setTexture(texture);
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4a5a8a
}

model-viewer {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #484E61
}

input[type="file"] {
  margin: 15px auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer@1.12.0/dist/model-viewer-umd.js"></script>
<h1>Upload an image to preview it in the model</h1>
<input type="file" id="urlA">
<model-viewer id="modelA" camera-controls src="https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb" shadow-intensity="0" environment-image="neutral" exposure="0.5"></model-viewer>
```